# Error con un archivo .exe generado desde un .jar en otra PC diferente a donde se generó

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans-8.2, jar

generé un archivo .exe desde un archivo .jar y funciona a las mil maravillas, pero solo en mi PC, al copiar ese archivo .exe a otra máquina e intentar ejecutarlo, no pasa de la ventana de logueo. [image: pantalla de logueo]

Mi aplicación es bastante sencilla, tego una tabla en una BD en Microsoft SQL Server Management con usuarios y roles (admin, trabajador)
[image: BD con tabla de usuarios]
En dependencia del rol del usuario deberia salirme una pantalla de bienvenida:

[image: log de un usuario admin]
[image: pantalla de bienvenida de un usuario admin]
[image: log de un usuario trabajador]
[image: pantalla de bienvenida de un usuario trabajador]
Me funciona a las mil maravillas en mi PC, peroooo, cuando copio el .exe a otra PC se queda en la pantalla de poner usuario y contraseña, y aunque se le inserten los datos bien, no muestra la pantalla de bienvenida. Adjunto codigo de mi clase conexion:

```
package conexiones;

import java.sql.*;

public class Conexion {
    
public static Connection obtenerConexion(){
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
            +"database=Trabajo;"
            +"user=sa;"
            +"password=rastafari*2022;"
            + "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
    
    
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        return con;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

y de mi boton conectar:

```
private void btn_ConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String user = tf_Usuario.getText();
        String pass = jPasswordField1.getText();
        
        //select nombre, password, privilegio from Usuarios where activo = 1 and nombre = 'greter'
        String url = "select nombre, password, privilegio "
                +"from Usuarios where activo = 1 and nombre = '"+user+"'";
        try {
            Connection con = conexiones.Conexion.obtenerConexion();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(url);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()){
                //si existe el usuario
                String u = rs.getString("nombre");
                String p = rs.getString("password");
                String priv = rs.getString("privilegio");
                
                if(pass.equals(p)){
                    //vamos a jframe admin o trabajador
                    if(priv.equals("trabajador")){
                        Trabajador ventanaTrabajador = new Trabajador();
                        ventanaTrabajador.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        ventanaTrabajador.setVisible(true);
                        this.setVisible(false);
                    }else if(priv.equals("admin")){
                        Admin ventanaAdmin = new Admin();
                        ventanaAdmin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        ventanaAdmin.setVisible(true);
                        this.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La contraseña es incorrecta");
                }
                
            }else{
                //el usuario no existe
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El usuario no existe");
            }
            
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Supongo que no se conecta desde otra pc porque tu cadena de conexión usa localhost y al usar otra pc a menos que tengas el mismo servidor con las mismas credenciales y bd, nunca se va a conectar. Además creo que no ves ningún mensjae de error porque en tus catch no usas algun mensaje o ventana para indicarle al usuario.

Comment: @javdromero esa era la intuición que tenía, que no se conecta porque uso un localhost, habrá alguna forma de arreglar ese error? Mi plan final es hacer una aplicación que se ejecute desde cualquier PC

Comment: Empezemos indicando que esto no es un error, más bien es el comportamiento normal de tu aplicación. Deberías empezar a investigar acerca de base de datos y cómo permitir que se acceda desde redes locales. Si deseas que "se ejecute desde cualquier PC" implica muchas más cosas como crear tu servidor o usar algun servicio de backend como back4app, etc.

Comment: @javdromero no habría alguna forma de lograr que la aplicación tomara los datos del localhost de mi PC (al ser ejecutada en otra) al final, solo va a ser instalada en 2 PC (aparte de la mia propia), he estado buscando pero no logro dar con la solución.

Comment: Si las 2 computadores están en la misma red, puedes abrir los puertos necesarios y con la ip de la computadora que tiene la base de datos, conectarte desde la otra computadora, ya que en tu cadena de conexión en vez de usar localhost, usas la ip

Comment: @javdromero justo lo acabo de probar con la ip de mi maquina desde otra maquina y me da error de driver y usuario y contraseña